# Html background colour behind border-radius

Tags: html, background-color, sticky, border-radius

I have an html table with the `thead` set as `position:sticky`, which works fine.  The row has `background-color` and `border-radius` set as you ca see here:

[image: header]

The problem is that when the rows scroll up 'behind' the header you can see them in the cut off corner.

[image]

So, how do I set the background colour that appears behind an element with a background colour and border radius?  Or is there some other way to stop this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The background must be on the element behind your `thead`.

Once you find which element has that color, put `overflow: hidden;` on that (parent) element.

Comment: The parent of my `thead` is a `table`, I tried setting the background color on that, it didn't work.  I then added a `<div>` around my whole table with a red background color, and that didn't work either :( The red was visible until I scrolled.

Comment: Share some code. Usually, it's easier to provide help with more evidence.